# In an infinite loop, is there any module that can temporary suspend a function of one of the variables for a specific time (eg. 10min)?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, stock

I have an infinite loop running code that gathers live data from an outside source.

```
while True:

    x = Livedata() # this should stop for 10 mins when x < 30, then restart.
    y = Livedata()
    z = Livedata()
```

I want the code to suspend gathering data for `N` minutes
for the `x` variable when a certain condition is met, e.g. `x < 30`.
The code should not stop gathering data for `y` and `z` when `x` is suspended. After `N` minutes, gather data for `x` again until the condition is met again.

Comment: You could consider multiprocessing and having the worker collecting the `x` data suspend for 10 minutes. But probably there is an easier solution.

Comment: Do you mean you want the code to stop gathering data for `x` when the condition `x < 30` is met?

Comment: That depends entirely on what `Livedata` actually returns. Presumably it's an object that wraps a separate thread of execution?

Comment: @Queuebee yes but not exactly, when x<30 I want the code to hold gathering data for x for (10min) while continuing to gather for y and z.

Comment: @chepner Livedata prints x or y or z if they were to be less than 30, otherwise it repeats it prints "Not Valid" and goes over to repeat the loop. The issue here is that suppose x came out to be 29, I dont want it to immediately go back to the loop and print x again, i prefer the code to stop gathering values of for 10min while running and gather y and z. After 10 min the code resumes gather x, y & z.

Comment: And these 10-minute intervals should keep happening when `x < 30`, correct?

Comment: So each call to `Livedata` returns (more or less) immediately, and the three calls are part of a loop? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Queuebee Exactly! Every time x is spotted to be <30 x should not be gathered for 10min.

Comment: If you find any of the answers helpful, consider accepting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think threads would be the best option, but if you want a thread-free way, you could use something like `time.time()` to keep track of every start moment for each thing you want to do.

This runs the code for `x` always if `x > 30`, otherwise it skips `x = liveData()` for 10 minutes. After 10 minutes it restarts. `y` and `z` just do what they already did.

```
import time

def minutesPast(end_time, start_time):
    return ( end_time - start_time ) / 60

TIME_INTERVAL = 10 # minutes

x_start = time.time()

# your loop
while True:

    time_now = time.time()

    # code for 'x'
    if ( x > 30 ) or (minutesPast(time_now, x_start) > TIME_INTERVAL) :
        x_start = time.time()
        x = liveData()

    y = liveData()
    z = liveData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiprocessing with the `threading` module:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

x = Thread(target=Livedata)
y = Thread(target=Livedata)
z = Thread(target=Livedata)

y.start() # Start y
z.start() # Start z
sleep(600)
x.start() # Only start x when 10 minutes have past
```